# How to pass the store in the constructor in a typescript class?

Tags: javascript, class, jestjs, ngrx, ngrx-selectors

I have this class sample that is using ngrx store an other services in the constructor, What is the best way to pass the store in the constructor when I am testing this class in jest?

This class is not a component or injectable.

```
export class Sample {
   private users;

   constructor(
      private readonly userService: UserService,
      private readonly store: Store
   ) { }

   public setUsersDataFromStore() {
       this.store.select(selectUsers).pipe(
           filter((user) => !!users),
           tap((users => (this.users = users)))
       ).subscribe();
   }
}
```

Unit test.

```
fit('should Sample Object defined', () => {
    const sampleObj = new Sample(
        mockUserService any,
        initialState as any
    );

    sampleObj.setUsersDataFromStore();

    expect(sampleObj.users).toBeDefined();
});
```

But the unit test is failing the selector is not getting the data from the initial state from the constructor, the initial state is a simple object, also I tried with the object in an observable of({initialState}), what is the best option to fix?

Comment: You need to provide a mocked store, either using NgRx's built-in mock store, or simply by creating a Jasmine Spy which mocks the select method, returning the mock Observable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getMockStore`](https://ngrx.io/api/store/testing/getMockStore) to create a mocked instance of the store, I briefly touch on it on this subject in my blog post [Testing an NgRx project](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/testing-an-ngrx-project#effects-that-use-the-ngrx-global-store).

```
new Sample(
 mockUserService,
  getMockStore({
      initialState,
  });
)
```